# How to make an overlapping barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, overlap

Making a barplot the 'standard' way

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A   B 
+ 1 1 4
+ 2 2 3
+ 3 3 2
+ 4 4 1", header = TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(dat))
```

gives a barplot like this:

[image]

Instead, I would like to have the different segnments to overlap, like so

[image]

How can I make such a plot in R?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired behavior.  Do you want something more like `barplot(as.matrix(dat), beside=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways I have used:

```
library('ggplot2')
counts <- with(diamonds, table(cut, clarity))
#            clarity
# cut           I1  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS1 VVS2 VVS1   IF
# Fair         210  466  408  261  170   69   17    9
# Good          96 1081 1560  978  648  286  186   71
# Very Good     84 2100 3240 2591 1775 1235  789  268
# Premium      205 2949 3575 3357 1989  870  616  230
# Ideal        146 2598 4282 5071 3589 2606 2047 1212
```

It is painfully easy in ggplot

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'identity', alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

In base R

```
cols <- ggcols(nrow(counts))

for (ii in 1:nrow(counts))
  barplot(counts[ii, ], add = ii != 1, ylim = c(0, 5000),
          col = adjustcolor(cols[ii], 0.3),
          axes = FALSE, axisnames = FALSE, border = NA)

axis(1, barplot(counts, plot = FALSE), colnames(counts))
axis(2, las = 1)
title(main = 'identity')
box(bty = 'l')

legend('topright', bty = 'n', title = 'cut',
       legend = rownames(counts), fill = adjustcolor(cols, 0.5))
```

[image]

And to match the ggplot colors:

```
ggcols <- function (n, l = 65, c = 100) {
  hues <- seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = l, c = c)[1:n]
}
```

Comment: I would add a `border=NA` argument to the base `barplot` function. Produces a more attractive output.

Comment: agreed. good call, also fixed the legend and margins in the edit. It was bothering me

Answer (score 4):

In plain R overlapping bar plots can also be achieved by :

1 - making bars transparent using the alpha value of the rgb function call (e.g., `rgb(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaLevel)`  by which `rgb(1, 0, 0, .5)` corresponds to red with an alpha level of .5)

2 - adding different bar plots on top of each other using the option `add=TRUE` in the call to barplot
Or in code:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A   B
  1 4
  2 3
  3 2
  4 1", header = TRUE)

barplot(dat$A, col=rgb(1, 0, 0, .5)) 
barplot(dat$B, col=rgb(0, 1, 0, .5), add=TRUE) 

# adding a legend
legend('top', bty = 'n', title = 'Legend',
  legend = c('A', 'B'), fill = c('red', 'green'))
```

The plot can be further prettified, but I believed this code provides a very simple alternative which would do the trick.