# Extracting and plotting key column of a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just learning R and working with the `iclaims` data set from the **bsts** library. The data frame is of the form

```
           claims
2004-01-04  2.536
2004-01-11  0.882
2004-01-18 -0.077
2004-01-25  0.135
2004-02-01  0.373
2004-02-08 -0.437
...        ...
```

The short-term goal is to plot this data using ggplot2. However, I need to set the x-axis to the column containing the date, which has no header. I have been referring to this as the key column, but many Google searches seem to indicate that this the wrong term.

So this question really has three parts:

1. What is the column containing the dates called?
2. How do you extract this column? Output should read along the lines of

   `2004-01-04
    2004-01-11
    2004-01-18
    2004-01-25
    2004-02-01
    2004-02-08
    ...`
3. When using ggplot2, how do you assign this column to x in the aes() argument?

Comment: I don't have this library installed, but those look like row names, which you can access with `row.names()`. For `ggplot` or many other operations, make a column in your data frame that contains these rownames, either by assigning a new column, or with `tibble::rownames_to_column`.

Comment: duplicate Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246070/how-to-use-names-and-rownames-of-a-dataframe-for-the-aes-of-ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have posted it looks as if that is the row names "column" which is not an actual column. you can access it with `row.names()`.

However to use it as a column you can convert it with:

```
data.tables::setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
```

Then it should have a name that you can use to plot.

Comment: Note that `setDT` is from `data.table`