# Overlap bar charts with transparency

Tags: r, plot, transparency, bar-chart

I have two charts created as below. I would like to show them together on one chart with the bars having a certain level of transparency so that both series are visible. How can this be done (I can use ggplot if that helps)?

```
widths1 = c(0.023,0.0507,0.0107,0.1148,0.0623,0.0173,0.0083,0.0189,0.0409,0.072,0.0341,0.0125,0.1083,0.0379,0.0504,0.1426,0.0372,0.0713,0.0932,0.0424,0.0822,0.0511)
heights1 = c(5.1,7.5,8.4,8.5,9.2,10.4,12.4,12.5,13.3,13.8,14.6,15.1,15.8,17.2,17.6,18,19.4,20.1,21,21.4,24.3,26)

widths2 = c(0.0716,0.0205,0.0568,0.0658,0.0261,0.0611,0.0313,0.0654,0.0644,0.0294,0.0448,0.0306,0.031,0.0454,0.0891,0.0181,0.0883,0.0765,0.0336,0.0396,0.0315,0.0227,0.0604,0.0394,0.0545)
heights2 =  c(8.3,9.7,11.5,11.8,13.8,14.3,15,15.4,15.8,16.5,17.1,17.1,18.1,19.9,19.9,20.4,21.2,21.6,21.8,24,24.5,24.9,26.6,28.2,29.9)

barplot(heights1, widths1, space=0, col=c("blue"))
barplot(heights2, widths2, space=0, col=c("red"))
```

So the areas where both bars appear would be purple I suspect.

Note: I have seen something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228273/829571) which looks close to what I'm after, but I'm not sure how I can adapt it to my use case (the chart on that example shows counts whereas I want to show the values of the heights series).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `alpha` argument of `rgb` to create a colour with transparency. Additional use `add=TRUE` in `barplot` to add the barplot to an existing one:

```
blue <- rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.5)
red <- rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.5)

barplot(heights1, widths1, space=0, col=blue)
barplot(heights2, widths2, space=0, col=red, add=TRUE)
```

[image]