# Plotting subset os subset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data.frame like following:

```
           files
Total      1000
Subset1     587
Subset2     123
```

I would like to represent the above data frame in a such way that of 123 files is a subset of 587 which itself subset of 1000. When I use pie or bar graphs, it is misleading.

My sincere apologies if my question is very amateurish. Kindly guide me how can represent the above data in R plots.

Comment: That count does not add up. If there are three categories the sum should come to 1000 and the count should be (587,123,290) else if there are two categories only, then count should be (587, 413). Once that is sorted you can go for a stacked bar plot or maybe a venn diagram in R.

Comment: Or use overlapping barplot with opacity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228082/how-to-make-an-overlapping-barplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
df = data.frame(files=c(1000,587,123),row.names = c('total','subset1','subset2'))
library(VennDiagram)
draw.triple.venn(area1 = df$files[1], area2 = df$files[2], area3 = df$files[3], 
                n12 = 587, n23 = 123, n13 = 123, n123 = 123, 
                category = c("Total", "Subset1", "Subset2"), 
                lty = "blank", fill = c("skyblue", "pink1", "mediumorchid"),
                cat.pos = 0,cat.dist = c(-0.02,-0.05,-0.02))
```

Result:

[image: venn diagram]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as follows:

```
df$files[1] <- df$files[1] - sum(df$files[-1])

pie(df$files, df$sets)
```

The result:

[image]

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="  sets         files
Total      1000
Subset1     587
Subset2     123 ", header=TRUE)
```